# Plone 4.0.7 - Maximum recursion depth error when checking in large PDF

Tags: plone

Recently one of our site users successfully checked out a large PDF and was trying to check it back in but it failed with the following stack trace:

```
2013-02-21 12:42:39 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1361450559.20.0921547927966    
http://phoebe:8095/portal/our-responsibilities/codes-of-conduct/copy_of_please-let-us-    
know-where-you-live/content_status_modify
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 42, in content_status_modify
   - <FSControllerPythonScript at /portal/our-responsibilities/codes-of-conduct/please- 
let-us-know-where-you-live/content_status_modify>
   - Line 42
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 244, in doActionFor
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 555, in _invokeWithNotification
  Module Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow, line 282, in doActionFor
  Module Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow, line 421, in _changeStateOf
  Module Products.DCWorkflow.DCWorkflow, line 465, in _executeTransition
  Module zope.event, line 23, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 26, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 138, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 323, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 575, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 34, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 138, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 323, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 575, in subscribers
  Module arcadia.app.events, line 22, in before_transition
  Module plone.app.iterate.browser.checkin, line 50, in __call__
  Module plone.app.iterate.policy, line 90, in checkin
  Module zope.event, line 23, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 26, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 138, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 323, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 575, in subscribers
  Module plone.app.iterate.subscribers.versioning, line 36, in handleAfterCheckin
  Module plone.app.iterate.archiver, line 43, in save
  Module Products.CMFEditions.CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool, line 297, in save
  Module Products.CMFEditions.CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool, line 443, in 
_recursiveSave
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ArchivistTool, line 267, in prepare
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ArchivistTool, line 221, in _cloneByPickle
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 843, in setstate
  Module logging, line 1047, in error
  Module logging, line 1128, in _log
  Module logging, line 1108, in makeRecord
  Module logging, line 243, in __init__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

The PDF in question is 24MB in size, checking in a PDF reduced down to 9MB didn't cause the problem.

A simple solution is to keep the size of the PDFs down, but the user is adament they wan the larger version (higher resolution for printing).

Does anyone know:

1. Whether there is a fix for thi issue?
2. What the maximum size of a BLOB that can be checked in is?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: File a bug report! http://dev.plone.org. This is the sort of problem that is very unlikely to be resolved on StackOverflow.

Comment: Or reopen https://dev.plone.org/ticket/7223 -- this is a long-standing CMFEditions issue which at best is just worked around (IIRC, see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to visit `/portal_modifier/SkipVersioningOfLargeFilesAndImages/modifierEditForm` in your site, and enable this modifier.  This will disable versioning for the uploaded file payload for files larger than the threshold specified, but enable versioning for any edited metadata.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, however it would appear this modifier is enabled on the site - it is in the list on the `portal_modifier` page anyway. There is no option to enable it, only import/export, move, delete, etc.

Comment: When I click the `SkipVersioningOfLargeFilesAndImages` link from the `portal_modifier` page, I get taken to a page that just shows: **Main Navigation

Tool Navigation

Site footer** with no option to enable the modifier